# Replacing Extra Line Feeds in SQL Server / T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to reformat a data column in SQL Server 2012 (SSMS v11.0.2100.60) that was submitted as free form text. It is formatted in standard paragraph form with CR/LF and tabs. The problem is the data is converted from HTML and after the re-format to text there are many extra CR/LF and tabs in the data and I'm trying to clean them up.

The data is passed into my function as `@vOut (varchar(max))`. The code below will be in a while loop until it finds a match.

```
DECLARE @vFind VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @vFix VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @VFind = CONCAT(CHAR(13),CHAR(09),CHAR(13));
SET @VFix = CONCAT(CHAR(13),CHAR(13));

IF CHARINDEX(@VFind, @vOut) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @vOut = REPLACE(@vOut, @VFind, @VFix );
END

---------------

SET @VFind = CONCAT(CHAR(13),CHAR(13),CHAR(13));
SET @VFix = CONCAT(CHAR(13),CHAR(13));

IF CHARINDEX(@vOut, @VFind) > 0
BEGIN
    SET @vOut = REPLACE(@vOut, @VFind, @VFix );
END
```

The result set should replace CHAR(13)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(13) with CHAR(13)+CHAR(13) to reserve the paragraph based formatting.

The charindex for both items above does return a value > 0, but the replaces are not working, so the data returned is the same.

Comment: Are you *sure* it isn't `CHAR(13) CHAR(10)` (Carriage return followed by LineBreak)?

Comment: Yes.  If I change my charindex to look for char(13)+char(10)+char(09)+char(13)+char(10), it returns 0,  But the way it is now i get the first position I am expecting.

Comment: are you trying to replace 3 line breaks with 2 line breaks?

Comment: Yes.  That is the end result I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

As Larnu wrote in the comments, you probably have CRLF-s instead of just CR-s. Try using these lines:

```
SET @VFind = CONCAT(CHAR(13),CHAR(10),CHAR(13),CHAR(10),CHAR(13),CHAR(10));
SET @VFix = CONCAT(CHAR(13),CHAR(10),CHAR(13),CHAR(10));
```

You may also have just LF-s (if the file comes from Unix/Mac machines), so also try these:

```
SET @VFind = CONCAT(CHAR(10),CHAR(10),CHAR(10));
SET @VFix = CONCAT(CHAR(10),CHAR(10));
```

Comment: I am sure it is just CHAR(13).  If I run a replace on just char(13) in the data field it converts the data from paragraph format to just one line.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for?

```
DECLARE @vOut VARCHAR(MAX)= 
's




K';
SELECT REPLACE( REPLACE( 
                    REPLACE(  
                            REPLACE(@vOut,CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'<>')
                             ,'><','')
                ,'<>','<><>')
        ,'<>',CHAR(13))
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this in a  loop so that I can remove other things that are causing the paragraph to be "dirty" (Ex: CHAR(13)+CHAR(09)+CHAR(13)) and then loop back through to check again.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not sure what difference it made, but i changed the CONCAT method and it seems to have made the difference.

```
SET @VFind = CONCAT(CHAR(13),CHAR(09),CHAR(13));
SET @VFix = CONCAT(CHAR(13),CHAR(13));
and
SET @VFind = CONCAT(CHAR(13),CHAR(13),CHAR(13));
SET @VFix = CONCAT(CHAR(13),CHAR(13));
to
SET @VFind = CHAR(13)+CHAR(09)+CHAR(13);
SET @VFix = CHAR(13)+CHAR(13);
and 
SET @VFind = CHAR(13)+CHAR(13)+CHAR(13);
SET @VFix = CHAR(13)+CHAR(13);
```

Comment: The different the concatenation method should not change anything. It probably worked after repeatedly running both the method with tabs and the one without it, alternatively.

Comment: TY @ Razvan.  I didn't think this should have made a difference, but I wasn't 100% sure.  I'll investigate this further when I've got some time.